# Random value from a database in a JTextField

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a database with the name "generator", inside that database there is a table called emails that contains a column where emails are stored.

How can I create the following function: by pressing a button I need to generate random data from the email column and display it in JTextLabel?

Comment: [http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-select-random-rows-in-mysql/](http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-select-random-rows-in-mysql/)

Comment: In MySQL it possible to get a random record with `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: Where would the "ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 10;"

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pdWxRVS

Answer (score 0):

I have a database with the name "generator", inside that database there is a table called emails that contains a column where emails are stored.

How can I create the following function: by pressing a button I need to generate random data from the email column and display it in JTextLabel?